# All integer solutions to $xy(x^2+y^2) = 2z^4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question I am stuck on:
Find all integer solutions to $xy(x^2+y^2) = 2z^4$.

Since the equation is homogenous, if $(x, y, z)$ is a solution then so is $(kx, ky, kz)$ for some constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, all triples of the form $(k , k, k)$ where $x \in \mathbb{N}$ are solutions because $(1, 1, 1)$ is a solution. This means that we only want to find the primitive solutions (a primitive solution is a solution that satisfies $\gcd(x, y, z) = 1$).

From here, I realized that x, y, and z can't all be even because of the assumption that $\gcd(x, y, z) = 1$. Moreover, its not hard to see that they can't all be odd, and $x$ and $y$ cannot be odd while $z$ being even by taking both sides $\bmod 4$. After this point I was not able to get any nontrivial progress.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem from here or by using a different approach?

Comment: Would knowing that either or both of $x$ and $y$ divide $z$ help in any way?

Comment: Why can't they all be odd? That can't be trivially true given that (1, 1, 1) is a solution.